# Join tables in unix

Tags: linux, database, unix, bioinformatics

I have 3 tables:

table 1

```
 a  1
 b  2
 c  3
```

table 2

```
 a  2
 b  2
 c  6
```

table 3

```
 a  9
 b  0
 c  1
```

And I want to join them but by adding a distinctive column, like this:

```
 table1   a  1
 table1   b  2
 table1   c  3
 table2   a  2
 table2   b  2
 table2   c  6
 table3   a  9
 table3   b  0
 table3   c  1
```

Using cat I can join tables, but How can I distinguish data among them? I would like to add a column to show this. Do I need to process the initial tables by adding a column with a specific name, then join tables? If so, how can I add a column with all its rows having the same name?

Comment: _grep -H . table* > result.dat_

Comment: Thanks. I tried that function but the only problem is that the resulted table showed 2 columns. The first column showed the table name with the first Data. Something like table1:a......

Comment: It's easy to fix -- _tr ':' '\t'_. Or whatever delimiter you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `awk` and use the filename as first column:

```
awk '{ print FILENAME, $0 }' table* > merged_table
```

---

**Edit:**

To remove the filename suffix, you could assign FILENAME to a variable and replace the suffix with an empty string:

```
awk '{ fname=FILENAME; sub(/\..+$/, "", fname); print fname, $0 }' table* > merged_table
```

To do this operation only once and not on every row, you could save the names in an array at startup and refer to them.
This only makes sense for huge input files:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++){
      fname=ARGV[i]
      sub(/\..+$/, "", fname)
      names[ARGV[i]]=fname
    }
  }
  { print names[FILENAME], $0 }
' table* > merged_table
```

Comment: Thank you so much. By using awk I obtained the result I needed but the names contained .txt I mean like this "table1.txt".... "table2.txt"..... How to print without ".txt"?